# TypeScript function parameter using an enum with strictFunctionTypes

Tags: typescript, enums, redux

So we are currently using all the strict options in TypeScript 2.9, this has allowed us to find a few issues in our codebase. But now I have run into an interesting challenge with using a JS library which requires an unique object type.

The structure is quite simple, We have an object where the keys are strings, the values are functions which take a single object where a type property is defined which is the same as the key of the object, Since we like enums we tried this:

```ts
const enum Actions {
    Resume = 'resume',
    Stop = 'stop'
}

type action = (data: { type: Actions }) => Promise<any>;

//Types of property 'type' are incompatible. Type Actions is not assignable to type Actions.Resume
export const actions: { [key in Actions]: action} = {
    [Actions.Resume]: (data: { type: Actions.Resume }) => {
        return Promise.resolve();
    },
    [Actions.Stop]: (data: { type: Actions.Stop }) => {
        return Promise.resolve();
    }
}
```

However since we use the strict options TypeScript has an problem with the functions their type argument (see [playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=const%20enum%20Actions%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20Resume%20%3D%20'resume'%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20Stop%20%3D%20'stop'%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2FTypes%20of%20property%20'type'%20are%20incompatible.%20Type%20Actions%20is%20not%20assignable%20to%20type%20Actions.Resume%0D%0Atype%20action%20%3D%20(data%3A%20%7B%20type%3A%20Actions%20%7D)%20%3D%3E%20Promise%3Cany%3E%3B%0D%0Aexport%20const%20actions%3A%20%7B%20%5Bkey%20in%20Actions%5D%3A%20action%7D%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%5BActions.Resume%5D%3A%20(data%3A%20%7B%20type%3A%20Actions.Resume%20%7D)%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20Promise.resolve()%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%5BActions.Stop%5D%3A%20(data%3A%20%7B%20type%3A%20Actions.Stop%20%7D)%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20Promise.resolve()%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2F%20Much%20rather%20this%20should%20also%20work%20%0D%0A%2F%2F%20(Extra%20parameters.%20Without%20losing%20the%20type%20strictness%20on%20the%20calling%20type)%0D%0A%2F%2F%20(So%20an%20index%20signature%20with%20type%20%60any%60%60%20is%20not%20preffered%2C%20no%20idea%20if%20this%20is%20even%20possible)%0D%0A%0D%0Atype%20action2%20%3D%20(data%3A%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20type%3A%20Actions%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%5Bkey%3A%20string%5D%3A%20any%3B%0D%0A%7D)%20%3D%3E%20Promise%3Cany%3E%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Ainterface%20Entry%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20foo%3A%20true%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aexport%20const%20actions2%3A%20%7B%20%5Bkey%20in%20Actions%5D%3A%20action2%7D%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%5BActions.Resume%5D%3A%20(data%3A%20%7B%20type%3A%20Actions.Resume%20%7D)%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20Promise.resolve()%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%5BActions.Stop%5D%3A%20(data%3A%20%7B%20type%3A%20Actions.Stop%2C%20entry%3A%20Entry%20%7D)%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20Promise.resolve()%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D)). The reason why we want to manually type the object is to verify that all enum options are present in the actions object (see the `{[key in Actions]...}` part). But this means we also have to type the functions else we lose the functions their type's.

I am wondering if this is even possible with the strictFunctionTypes check or if there is another solution to this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure about that error, but you could try this:

```
type Action<T> = (data: { type: T }) => Promise<any>;

export const actions: { [P in Actions]: Action<P> } = {
    [Actions.Resume]: (data: { type: Actions.Resume }) => {
        return Promise.resolve();
    },
    [Actions.Stop]: (data: { type: Actions.Stop }) => {
        return Promise.resolve();
    }
}
```

This will also prevent you from having a mismatch between your `actions` object keys and the `data.type` the callback should accept, which I think is what you want:

```
export const actions: { [P in Actions]: Action<P> } = {
    [Actions.Resume]: (data: { type: Actions.Stop }) => {
        return Promise.resolve();
    }
}
```

> Type '{ type: Actions.Resume; }' is not assignable to type '{ type: Actions.Stop; }'

In fact, the callback `data` type should be contextually typed now:

```
export const actions: { [P in Actions]: Action<P> } = {
    [Actions.Stop]: data => {
        data.type // Actions.Stop
        return Promise.resolve();
    }
}
```

Comment: Aah combining the generic `P` from `P in Actions` and pass it along to the `Action type`, brilliant! Thanks a ton!